# Memory issue when searching for an copying files using python and a csv list

Tags: python, memory

I don't understand why my script is failing with an out of memory error after it runs about 200 tiles. I have looked at the script and am not sure what it's writing to memory that is so large that it fails...

The script

```
import os, glob, arcpy, csv, sys, shutil, datetime
top = r'L:\Raster_Data' # Source directory for all files to check and process
#top = os.getcwd()
RootOutput = r'H:\Raster' # Directory to copy/move files to
FileList = csv.reader(open(r'P:\2013\508_Data_Split_MSC\Working\LiDAR_Tiles_index2_MSC.csv')) # list of files to use with unique name
RootDirDelete="L:\\" #repatative name of roor file path to remove from new directory name
filecount=0
successcount=0
errorcount=0

print "Working in: "+ top

list =[]
f = open(RootOutput+'\\Success_LOG.txt', 'a')
f.write("Log of files Succesfully processed. RESULT of process run @:"+str(datetime.datetime.now())+"\n")
f.close()

for File in FileList:
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=False):
    for directory in dirs:
        currentPath=os.path.join(root,directory)
        os.chdir(currentPath)
        #arcpy.env.workspace = currentPath
        print os.getcwd()
        lstFCs = glob.glob('*'+File[0]+'*.*')
        print lstFCs
        for fc in lstFCs:
            OutPutDir=RootOutput+"\\"+str(os.getcwd()).strip(RootDirDelete)
            filecount=filecount+1
            if OutPutDir.endswith(".gdb"):
                print "File in GDB...SKIPPING"
            else:
                try:
                    os.makedirs(OutPutDir)
                    print "Created: "+OutPutDir
                except:
                    #pass
                    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]

                try:
                    fcIn=currentPath+"\\"+fc
                    fcOut=OutPutDir+"\\"+fc
                    successcount=successcount+1
                    print "Copied: "+fcIn+" to " +fcOut
                    shutil.copy2(fcIn,fcOut)
                    f = open(RootOutput+'\\Success_LOG.txt', 'a')
                    f.write(str(filecount)+","+str(successcount)+","+str(fcIn)+","+str(fcOut)+"\n")
                    f.close()

                except:
                    #pass
                    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
                    errorcount=errorcount+1
                    f = open(RootOutput+'\\Error_LOG.txt', 'a')
                    f.write(str(filecount)+","+str(errorcount)+","+str(fcIn)+","+str(fcOut)+","+str(sys.exc_info()[0])+"\n")
                    f.close()
```

The error report.

```
L:\Raster_Data\Satellite_Imagery\Spot\Eastern_QLD_and_TRC_2010\Shapefiles\AUO_Australia
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 73, in execInThread
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 196, in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 71, in syncreq
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 431, in sync_request
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 379, in serve
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 337, in _recv
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\channel.py", line 50, in recv
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\stream.py", line 166, in read
EOFError: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>>> 
*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized  ***
>>>
```

Here's the error:
[image]

Comment: If you post your code please keep it PEP8 compliant. Mixing 2 and 4 spaces per indentation is a bad idea.

Comment: How are you running this program? Are you using an IDE, or are you typing `python myprog.py` into a shell, or something else?

Comment: Also, what makes you think there is an out-of-memory error? The error messages that I see are "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" and "Remote Interpreter Reinitialized". Neither of those mention memory.

Comment: Sorry. The out of memory comes up in a box over PyScripter (the IDE I use) and I didn't get a screen grab of that but that's what it said.

Comment: @Robᵩ -the memory error came again and I have included a screen shot now.

Comment: The traceback indicates that this is a problem with your IDE, not your program. Please try running your program outside of the IDE, from a cmd.exe window.

Comment: Thanks Mate...so far it seems to be working fine in IDLE. If you want to add that as an answer I would be happy to accept it.